# javascript slideshow pauseonhover

Tags: javascript, slider

my question is really simple and something can help a lot of people out there,

I want my slideshow to NOT stop when someone hover over it,

I was able to do it for one of my sites, by accessing the .js (nivooSlider.js) and adding to the list of options: the "false" value to the pauseOnHover option (pauseOnHover: false,)
and that did it! ...

Now I'm also trying to get the same result in another of my websites that is currently using rokSlider, which does not have that option by default, so i'm wondering, if i go to the options list and simple add this options+value ... Do you think that will work?

Regards

```
var Slideshow = new Class({

    version: '3.0.3',

    options: {
        captions: true,
        showTitleCaption: true,
        classes: ['prev', 'next', 'active'],
        duration: [2000, 4000],
        path: '/',
        navigation: false,
        pan: 100,
        resize: true,
        thumbnailre: [/\./, 't.'],
        transition: Fx.Transitions.Sine.easeInOut,
        type: 'fade',
        zoom: 50,
        loadingDiv: true,
        removeDiv: true
    },

    styles: {
        caps: {
            div: {
                opacity: 0,
                position: 'absolute',
                width: '100%',
                margin: 0,
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                height: 40,
                background: '#333',
                color: '#fff',
                textIndent: 0       
            },

            h2: {
                color: 'red',
                padding: 0,
                fontSize: '80%',
                margin: 0,
                margin: '2px 5px',
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },

            p: {
                padding: 0,
                fontSize: '60%',
                margin: '2px 5px',
                color: '#eee'
            }
        }   
    },

    initialize: function(el, options) {
        this.setOptions($merge({
            onClick: this.onClick.bind(this)
        }, options));

        if(!this.options.images) return;
        this.options.pan = this.mask(this.options.pan);
        this.options.zoom = this.mask(this.options.zoom);

        this.el = $(el).empty();

        this.caps = {
            div: new Element('div', {
                styles: this.styles.caps.div,
                'class': 'captionDiv'
            }),
            h2: new Element('h2', {
                styles: this.styles.caps.h2,
                'class': 'captionTitle'
            }),
            p: new Element('p', {
                styles: this.styles.caps.p,
                'class': 'captionDescription'
            })
        };

        this.fx = [];

        var trash = new ImageLoader(this.el, this.options.images, {
            loadingDiv: this.options.loadingDiv,
            onComplete: this.start.bind(this),
            path: this.options.path,
            removeDiv: this.options.removeDiv
        });
    },

    start: function() {
        this.imgs = $A(arguments);
        this.a = this.imgs[0].clone().set({         
            styles: {
                display: 'block',
                position: 'absolute',
                left: 0,
                'top': 0,
                zIndex: 1
            }
        }).injectInside(this.el);

        var obj = this.a.getCoordinates();
        this.height = this.options.height || obj.height;
        this.width = this.options.width || obj.width;

        this.el.setStyles({
            display: 'block',
            position: 'relative',
            width: this.width
        });

        this.el.empty();
        this.el.adopt((new Element('div', {
            events: {
                'click': this.onClick.bind(this)
            },
            styles: {
                display: 'block',
                overflow: 'hidden',
                position: 'relative',
                width: this.width,
                height: this.height
            }
        })).adopt(this.a));

        this.resize(this.a, obj);
        this.b = this.a.clone().setStyle('opacity', 0).injectAfter(this.a);

        this.timer = [0, 0];
        this.navigation();

        this.direction = 'left';
        this.curr = [0,0];

        $(document.body).adopt(new Element('div', {
            id: 'hiddenDIV',
            styles: {
                visibility: 'hidden',
                height: 0,
                width: 0,
                overflow: 'hidden',
                opacity: 0
            }
        }));
        this.loader = this.imgs[0];
        $('hiddenDIV').adopt(this.loader);
        this.load();
    },

    load: function(fast) {
        if ($time() > this.timer[0]) {
            this.img = (this.curr[1] % 2) ? this.b : this.a;
            this.img.setStyles({
                opacity: 0,
                width: 'auto',
                height: 'auto',
                zIndex: this.curr[1]
            });

            var url = this.options.images[this.curr[0]].url;
            this.img.setStyle('cursor', (url != '#' && url != '') ? 'pointer' : 'default');

            this.img.setProperties({
                src: this.loader.src,
                title: this.loader.title,
                alt: this.loader.alt
            });

            this.resize(this.img, this.loader);

            if(fast){
                this.img.setStyles({
                    top: 0,
                    left: 0,
                    opacity: 1
                });

                this.captions();
                this.loaded();          
                return;
            }

            this.captions();
            this[this.options.type.test(/push|wipe/) ? 'swipe' : 'kens']();
            this.loaded();
        } else {
            this.timeout = this.load.delay(100, this);
        }
    },

    loaded: function() {
        if(this.ul) {
            this.ul.getElements('a[name]').each(function(a, i) {
                a[(i === this.curr[0] ? 'add' : 'remove') + 'Class'](this.options.classes[2]);
            }, this);
        }

        this.direction = 'left';
        this.curr[0] = (this.curr[0] + 1) % this.imgs.length;
        this.curr[1]++;

        this.timer[0] = $time() + this.options.duration[1] + (this.options.type.test(/fade|push|wipe/) ? this.options.duration[0] : 0);     
        this.timer[1] = $time() + this.options.duration[0];

        this.loader = this.imgs[this.curr[0]];
        $('hiddenDIV').empty().adopt(this.loader);
        this.load();
    },

    kens: function() {
        this.img.setStyles({
            bottom: 'auto',
            right: 'auto',
            left: 'auto',
            top: 'auto'
        });

        var arr = ['left top', 'right top', 'left bottom', 'right bottom'].getRandom().split(' ');
        arr.each(function(p) {
            this.img.setStyle(p, 0);
        }, this);

        var zoom = this.options.type.test(/zoom|combo/) ? this.zoom() : {};
        var pan = this.options.type.test(/pan|combo/) ? this.pan(arr) : {};

        this.fx.push(this.img.effect('opacity', {duration: this.options.duration[0]}).start(1));
        this.fx.push(this.img.effects({duration: this.options.duration[0] + this.options.duration[1]}).start($merge(zoom, pan)));
    },

    zoom: function() {
        var n = Math.max(this.width / this.loader.width, this.height / this.loader.height);
        var z = (this.options.zoom === 'rand') ? Math.random() + 1 : (this.options.zoom.toInt() / 100.0) + 1;

        var eh = Math.ceil(this.loader.height * n);
        var ew = Math.ceil(this.loader.width * n);

        var sh = (eh * z).toInt();
        var sw = (ew * z).toInt();

        return {height: [sh, eh], width: [sw, ew]};
    },

    pan: function(arr) {
        var ex = this.width - this.img.width, ey = this.height - this.img.height;
        var p = this.options.pan === 'rand' ? Math.random() : Math.abs((this.options.pan.toInt() / 100) - 1);
        var sx = (ex * p).toInt(), sy = (ey * p).toInt();

        var x = this.width / this.loader.width > this.height / this.loader.height;
        var obj = {};
        obj[arr[x ? 1 : 0]] = x ? [sy, ey] : [sx, ex];
        return obj;
    },

    swipe: function() {
        var arr, p0 = {}, p1 = {}, x;
        this.img.setStyles({
            left: 'auto',
            right: 'auto',
            opacity: 1
        }).setStyle(this.direction, this.width);

        if(this.options.type === 'wipe') {
            this.fx.push(this.img.effect(this.direction, {
                duration: this.options.duration[0],
                transition: this.options.transition
            }).start(0));           
        } else {
            arr = [this.img, this.curr[1] % 2 ? this.a : this.b];
            p0[this.direction] = [this.width, 0];
            p1[this.direction] = [0, -this.width];

            if(arr[1].getStyle(this.direction) === 'auto') {
                x = this.width - arr[1].getStyle('width').toInt();

                arr[1].setStyle(this.direction, x);
                arr[1].setStyle(this.direction === 'left' ? 'right' : 'left', 'auto');

                p1[this.direction][0] = x;
            }

            this.fx.push(new Fx.Elements(arr, {
                duration: this.options.duration[0],
                transition: this.options.transition
            }).start({
                '0': p0,
                '1': p1
            }));
        }
    },

    captions: function(img) {
        img = img || this.img;
        if(!this.options.captions || (!img.title && !img.alt)) return;

        this.el.getFirst().adopt(this.caps.div.adopt(this.caps.h2, this.caps.p));

        (function () {
            if (this.options.showTitleCaption) this.caps.h2.setHTML(img.title);
            this.caps.p.setHTML(img.alt);
            this.caps.div.setStyle('zIndex', img.getStyle('zIndex')*2 || 10);

            this.capsHeight = this.capsHeight || this.options.captionHeight || this.caps.div.offsetHeight;

            var fx = this.caps.div.effects().set({'height': 0}).start({
                opacity: 0.7,
                height: this.capsHeight
            });

            (function(){
                fx.start({
                    opacity: 0,
                    height: 0
                });
            }).delay(1.00*(this.options.duration[1] - this.options.duration[0]));
        }).delay(0.75*(this.options.duration[0]), this);
    },

    navigation: function() {
        if(!this.options.navigation) return;
        var i, j, atemp;
        var fast = this.options.navigation.test(/fast/) ;
        this.ul = new Element('ul');
        var li = new Element('li'), a = new Element('a');

        if (this.options.navigation.test(/arrows/)) {
            this.ul.adopt(li.clone()
                .adopt(a.clone()
                    .addClass(this.options.classes[0])
                    .addEvent('click', function() {
                        if (fast || $time() > this.timer[1]) {  
                            $clear(this.timeout);

                            // Clear the FX array only for fast navigation since this stops combo effects
                            if(fast) {
                                this.fx.each(function(fx) {
                                    fx.time = 0;
                                    fx.options.duration = 0;
                                    fx.stop(true);
                                });
                            }

                            this.direction = 'right';
                            this.curr[0] = (this.curr[0] < 2) ? this.imgs.length - (2 - this.curr[0]) : this.curr[0] - 2;
                            this.timer = [0];

                            this.loader = this.imgs[this.curr[0]];
                            this.load(fast);
                        }
                    }.bind(this))
                )
            );
        }

        if (this.options.navigation.test(/arrows\+|thumbnails/)) {
            for (i = 0, j = this.imgs.length; i < j; i++) {
                atemp = a.clone().setProperty('name', i);
                if (this.options.navigation.test(/thumbnails/)) atemp.setStyle('background-image', 'url(' + this.imgs[i].src + ')');
                if(i === 0) a.className = this.options.classes[2];

                atemp.onclick = function(i) {
                    if(fast || $time() > this.timer[1]) {
                        $clear(this.timeout);

                        if (fast) {
                            this.fx.each(function(fx) {
                                fx.time = 0;
                                fx.options.duration = 0;
                                fx.stop(true);
                            });
                        }

                        this.direction = (i < this.curr[0] || this.curr[0] === 0) ? 'right' : 'left';
                        this.curr[0] = i;
                        this.timer = [0];           

                        this.loader = this.imgs[this.curr[0]];                          
                        this.load(fast);
                    }
                }.pass(i, this);

                this.ul.adopt(li.clone().adopt(atemp));
            }
        }

        if (this.options.navigation.test(/arrows/)) {
            this.ul.adopt(li.clone()
                .adopt(a.clone()
                    .addClass(this.options.classes[1])
                    .addEvent('click', function() {
                        if (fast || $time() > this.timer[1]) {  
                            $clear(this.timeout);

                            // Clear the FX array only for fast navigation since this stops combo effects
                            if (fast) {
                                this.fx.each(function(fx) { 
                                    fx.time = 0;
                                    fx.options.duration = 0;
                                    fx.stop(true); 
                                });
                            }

                            this.timer = [0];                   

                            this.load(fast);
                        }
                    }.bind(this))
                )
            );
        }

        this.ul.injectInside(this.el);
    },

    onClick: function(e) {
        e = new Event(e).stop();
        var cur = this.curr[1] % this.imgs.length;
        var index = this.curr[1] == 0 ? 1 : cur == 0 ? this.imgs.length : cur;
        var url = this.options.images[index - 1].url;
        if(url == '#' || url == '') return;
        window.location.href = url;
    },

    mask: function(val, set, lower, higher) {
        if(val != 'rand') {
            val = val.toInt();
            val = isNaN(val) || val < lower || val > higher ? set : val;
        }

        return val;
    },

    resize: function(obj, to) {
        var n;
        if(this.options.resize) {
            n = Math.max(this.width / to.width, this.height / to.height);
            obj.setStyles({
                height: Math.ceil(to.height*n),
                width: Math.ceil(to.width*n)
            });
        }
    }
});
Slideshow.implement(new Options);

/**

 * 
 * 
 *
 */
var ImageLoader = new Class({

    version:'.5-olmo-ver',

    options: {
        loadingDiv    : false,
        loadingPrefix : 'loading images: ',
        loadingSuffix : '',
        path          : '',
        removeDiv     : true
    },

    initialize: function(container, sources, options){
        this.setOptions(options);
        this.loadingDiv = (this.options.loadingDiv) ? $(container) : false;
        this.images     = [];
        this.index      = 0;
        this.total      = sources.length;

        if(this.loadingDiv) {
            this.loadingText = new Element('div').injectInside(this.loadingDiv);
            this.progressBar = new Element('div', {
                styles: {
                    width: 100,
                    padding: 1,
                    margin: '5px auto',
                    textAlign: 'left',
                    overflow: 'hidden',
                    border: 'solid 1px #333'
                }
            }).adopt(new Element('div', {
                styles: {
                    width: '0%',
                    height: 10,
                    backgroundColor: '#333'
                }
            })).injectInside(this.loadingDiv);
        }

        this.loadImages.delay(200, this, [sources]);
    },

    reset: function() {
        this.index = 0;
        if(this.loadingDiv) {
            this.progressBar.getFirst().setStyle('width', '0%');
            this.loadingText.setHTML(this.options.loadingPrefix);
        }
    },

    loadImages: function(sources) {
        var self = this;
        this.reset();
        this.images  = [];
        this.sources = sources;

        this.timer = setInterval(this.loadProgress.bind(this), 100);
        for(var i = 0, j = sources.length; i < j; i++) {
            this.images[i] = new Asset.image((this.sources[i].path || this.options.path) + this.sources[i].file, {
                title: self.sources[i].title,
                alt: self.sources[i].desc,
                'onload'  : function(){ self.index++; },
                'onerror' : function(){ self.index++; self.images.splice(i,1); },
                'onabort' : function(){ self.index++; self.images.splice(i,1); }
            });
        }
    },

    loadProgress: function() {
        if(this.loadingDiv) {
            this.loadingText.setHTML(this.options.loadingPrefix + this.index + '/' + this.total + this.options.loadingSuffix);
            this.progressBar.getFirst().setStyle('width', (!this.total ? 0 : this.index.toInt()*100 / this.total) + '%');
        }

        if(this.index >= this.total) {
            this.loadComplete();
        } 
    },

    loadComplete: function(){
        $clear(this.timer);
        if(this.loadingDiv) {
            this.loadingText.setHTML('Loading Complete');

            if(this.options.removeDiv) {
                this.loadingText.empty().remove();
                this.progressBar.empty().remove();
            }
        }
        this.fireEvent('onComplete', this.images);
    },

    cancel: function(){
        $clear(this.timer);
    }

});

ImageLoader.implement(new Events, new Options);
```

Comment: nope.. if the plugin does not support it, you will have to implement  it, or create a workaround...

Answer (score 0):

If the slider stops on mouseover event, you can try:

```
$('#sliderSelector').mouseover(function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
});
```

or:

```
$('#sliderSelector').mouseover(function () {
    return false;
});
```

If the function in the plugin is only stoping the slider, then it should work. If there's more behind it will probably fail.
If this is not working: can you provide plugin code? (I coudnt't find it using google)